# Finding time t for a body with air resistance k to reach to location x

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Since gravity for this problem is irrelevant I started from the following equation:

$$ma = -kv$$

From here I integrated both sides in order to find an expression of v as a function of t:

- V stands for initial velocity.
  $$-\frac{m}{k}*\int_V^v \frac1{v}dv = \int_0^tdt$$
  which leads to:
  $$v=V*e^{-\frac{kt}m}$$
  I integrated both sides again:
  $$V\int_0^te^{-\frac{kt}m}dt=\int_0^xdx ⇒ -\frac{m}ke^{-\frac{kt}m}+\frac{m}k=\frac{x}V⇒e^{\frac{kt}m}=\frac{mV}{mV-kx}$$
  $$t=\frac{m}k*\ln{\frac{mV}{mV-kx}}$$
  The problem with this solution is that it works only if $mV>kx$.
  I wonder if there is a solution that works for every $x>0$ or maybe I just missed something on the way.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $t$ is the time to reach a given $x$.  If $kx \gt mV$, you will never get there, which is what the equation is telling you.

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes sense. I didn't think about it before. Apparently when mV=kx the objedct's speed is 0.

Comment: If you invert the equation, it only reaches $x=mV/k$ at infinite time.